IonInput CSS Custom Properties did not work for helper text
I noticed that the CSS Custom Properties did not work for the helper text. I tried to change the helper text color and nothing happened. Is there a workaround or some way of defining the Custom Properties to account for helper text separately? The below code just gives the same colour as the input field, which doesn't help. I'm using the stock colours rn
//for the input field
<template>
   <ion-input  label-placement="floating" color="primary"  fill="outline" placeholder="Text" label="title" helper-text="error" helper-text-color ="danger">
  </ion-input>
  <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" aria-label="Show/hide">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :icon="eyeOff" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { IonInput} from '@ionic/vue';
  import { eyeOff } from 'ionicons/icons';
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      IonInput},
      setup() {return { eyeOff };
      },
  });
</script>

//the color code
/* Dark Mode Colors */
:root {
    --ion-color-danger: #c5000f;
    --ion-color-danger-rgb: 197, 0, 15;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-danger-shade: #ad000d;
    --ion-color-danger-tint: #cb1a27;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    :root {
        --ion-color-danger: #cb1a27;
        --ion-color-danger-rgb: 203, 26, 39;
        --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
        --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
        --ion-color-danger-shade: #b01720;
        --ion-color-danger-tint: #d2343f;
    }
}
span.ion-text-left {
    margin-right: auto;
}

this is what im currently working with

Are you using ionic5? Can you once check the ionic version used?

im using ionic 7

You can modify the css for the input by adding a class on the input and then modifying the helper-text class inside the input.
<template>
  <ion-input label-placement="floating" color="primary" fill="outline" placeholder="Text" label="title" helper-text="error" class="custom"></ion-input>
  <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" aria-label="Show/hide">
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :icon="eyeOff" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { IonInput } from '@ionic/vue';
  import { eyeOff } from 'ionicons/icons';
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      IonInput
    },
    setup() {
      return {
        eyeOff
      };
    },
  });
</script>

//the color code
/* Dark Mode Colors */
:root {
  --ion-color-danger: #c5000f;
  --ion-color-danger-rgb: 197, 0, 15;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-danger-shade: #ad000d;
  --ion-color-danger-tint: #cb1a27;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --ion-color-danger: #cb1a27;
    --ion-color-danger-rgb: 203, 26, 39;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-danger-shade: #b01720;
    --ion-color-danger-tint: #d2343f;
  }
}
span.ion-text-left {
  margin-right: auto;
}

ion-input.custom.ios .input-bottom .helper-text,
ion-input.custom.md .input-bottom .helper-text {
  color: var(--ion-color-danger)
}

Here, I have added the color for supporting both the ios and md mode but you can define it specific to a platform if required.
